# Vietnamese Sandwiches - Spread Identification?

Tags: sandwich

A short while ago, I was on vacation, and ate several times at a Vietnamese sandwich shop (in North America) that served what were presented as traditional Vietnamese style sandwiches.

While most of the ingredients were self-explanatory, one of them was something I've never tasted or seen anywhere else: it was a sandwich spread with a light(?) grey color, and a slight texture similar to a thin sort of pate. The pate was a bit sweet to taste, but otherwise didn't taste familiar (not obviously fishy/beefy/chickeny, etc.).

From what I understand, pate and similar spreads are common in Vietnamese cuisine, but I'm having a hard time narrowing the possibilities down further to ones that match the above description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pate can vary in color depending on what you put in it, so I'd say what you were eating was pate!

Here's a pate recipe with a resultant gray hue: http://berriesandspice.com/vietnamese-banh-mi-pate/

Comment: Hmm, so based on that, it's probably a chicken liver based pate, with possibly another meat mixed in. Works for me, thanks!